# JavaScript - Get size of element in HTML file without using CSS file and style tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got this simple test HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function test()
    {
        alert (document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].style.width);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button id="buttonTest" onClick="test()" >
            Test it!
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't have a CSS file though, but I would like to get the size and other properties of the respective HTML element (button in this case), but this does only seem to work if they are not set priorly.

Is there a way to get the measures and other properties like background color or font (color) of e.g. buttons when they are not preset but defined by the content?

Kind regards,
jaySon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].offsetWidth
```

Use offsetWidth on the element not on the style property.

Comment: Alright, that works, thanks. But how about color and other attributes?

Comment: color comes through style, you don't need a css style on an element for it to have a color in the style property. What other attributes? There are plenty of DOM properties available :)

Comment: Sure, the color comes through CSS, but a default button has a default color. I'd need that for measuring purposes. Other properties would be font (color). I imagine having seen that for other elements than button (also without CSS), is that right?

Comment: if you use chrome's inspector and go to the computed part of the styles it will show you all of the styles that are currently loaded for that element and their names. From there you can work out which you want to work with and how to work with them

Comment: Alright, Chrome obviously provides a lot more information than Firefox. But it seems like I cannot access these settings using e.g. _".style.text-align"_, can I?

Comment: firefox has this too, every single property the browser calculated for the element will be there

Comment: OK, I could access the DOM using Firebug, but not with the default inspector. Anyway, I still don't seem to access the by default defined properties as I mentioned in my last comment. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Get `offsetWidth` directly from the element:

```
alert (document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].offsetWidth);
```

Edit: For other inherited attributes, jQuery's css(). [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/92sgqnya/). Or you can use window.[getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle).

Comment: Alright, that works, thanks. But how about color and other attributes?